# Creating An Array Without Duplicates From A MySQL Result in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, foreach

I am trying to do a select statement from my MySQL DB in PHP using PDO. I successfully create an array with the query results. But then, I want to filter out duplicate entries with the same date, thus creating an array of dates.

```
function grabUsefulDates() {
$sql = "SELECT DATETIME, pointcount FROM `fjbarrett`";
$sql_array = dbSelect($sql);
$datesarray = array();
$i = 0;
while($i < count($sql_array)) {
    if (count($datesarray) == 0) {
        $datesarray[] = datetimeConvertToDate($sql_array[$i]['DATETIME']);
        echo "rollone";
    } else {
        foreach ($datesarray as $f => $date) {
            if ($date !== datetimeConvertToDate($sql_array[$i]['DATETIME'])) {
                echo $date;
                echo " " . datetimeConvertToDate($sql_array[$i]['DATETIME']);
                echo "<br>";
                $datesarray[] = datetimeConvertToDate($sql_array[$i]['DATETIME']);
            }
        }
        }
        $i++;
    }
var_dump($datesarray);
}
```

This code will not run, but when I remove the "add to array" line within the foreach loop, it will run. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you removed the "add to array" line from the post too? I see nothing resembling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATETIME, pointcount FROM `fjbarrett`;
```

Comment: Definitely helped. Had no idea about the DISTINCT function in MySQL. Thanks!